# How is Gmail better or worse than Alumni email or a temporary institutional email?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, paper-submission, email, affiliation

The majority of researchers use "edu" emails on their **research publication**, when some academia use Gmail as the corresponding address.

Many of the young researchers do not have a permanent "edu" email address. It is seem to be [consensus of this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/96503/what-email-to-use-for-corresponding-author-on-publications-when-institution-is-n) that Gmail is better than temporary emails and alumni emails. According to other answers, the Gmail option receive much more upvotes than the alumni option.

Established researchers and people on this site heavily promote Gmail; in contrast, on research papers, the vast **majority** of the junior researchers **put their temporary institutional address** rather than Gmail. Although I cannot find a research article backing up my "statistical findings", I am quite sure about this at least for students in my school.

In my opinion, alumni email combines the advantages of both Gmail (permanent) and institutional email (credible). However, people do **use Gmail much more often than alumni email**. I've read or skimmed thousands of papers and alumni address was noticed only **once**. I guess it might be weird if the email address and the affiliation come from different educational institutes?

So I ask: how is Gmail way better than the alumni email or temporary email? If Gmail is so good, why do people still use temporary emails at the most of the times? If I have a permanent alumni address, is it a choice better than my temporary address or Gmail address?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing the purpose for which you are using the email address.  Teaching?  Contact information in a publication?  Joining the alumni association?  In any case, your choice of email address matters little.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Contact info in research publication

Comment: I guess the cited answer isn't representative.

Comment: I don't see anything contradictory here. What precisely is claimed to be the contradiction?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoftto The majority here voted for "Gmail" while the people in real life vote for the other option.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica That is a good point. There are at least three QAs here on this site arguing Gmail is a very good option for junior researchers; those answers get a lot of upvotes. For example this one: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2873/69151.

Comment: How is that a contradiction? That just indicates that the group of people you have looked at either do not follow the advice given or have not heard the advice.

Comment: Your edit did not actually make the question clearer.

Comment: This thread recommends you use a custom domain: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122253/choosing-an-email-address-provider-for-academic-work-as-you-change-positons The answer you cite doesn't recommend gmail. It just says using Gmail isn't objectionable. Given its context, I actually interpret the answer as saying: if (given frequent changes between short term positions) you can't use an institutional email address, gmail isn't worse than other solutions.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica You are definitely correct; however, this specific thread receives little attention and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email address listed in a publication (per clarification in the comments) does not matter at all, so long as you can read email sent to it.

Most of the email you will receive will be from automated systems.  I use a unique email address for each publication.  These unique email addresses receive many requests for money from fraudulent journals.

Exception:  According to rumor, a few universities have (insane) rules requiring you to use a particular email address in your publications.

Comment: I didn't know why people downvoted. From my experience, once you block those fraudulent journals, you can easily see some honorable communications such as questions and material requests.